# Links are opening in Android webview creating multiple instances

Tags: android, android-studio, webview, deep-linking

I am working on an Android webview app and opening www.xyz.com in it. 
When the app is running in the background and if I try to open Whatsapp/SMS received message-www.xyz.com/example then it is opening in a new instance and not opening in the already running instance which is in background. 
And when I tried using android:launchMode="singleTask" it resumes www.xyz.com only instead of opening www.xyz.com/example.

Below is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:host="www.xyz.com"
                    android:scheme="https"
                    />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Below is the MainActivity.java code -

```
protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        if (data != null && data.isHierarchical()) {
            String uri = this.getIntent().getDataString();
            myWebView.loadUrl(uri);
            Log.i("MyApp", "Deep link clicked " + uri);
        }
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong? Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

By using `launchMode="singleTask"` and according to Android docs (see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack):

> The system creates a new task and instantiates the activity at the
>   root of the new task. However, if an instance of the activity already
>   exists in a separate task, the system routes the intent to the
>   existing instance through a call to its onNewIntent() method, rather
>   than creating a new instance. Only one instance of the activity can
>   exist at a time.

Add to your main activity an `onNewIntent` handler where you should see the new URL being passed in *newIntent*:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent newIntent)
{
     // reload WebView
}
```

Additionally, I'm not sure that using `onResume` to `mywebView.loadUrl()` is a good or necessary practice, as even simple pause/resume events would lead to the page being reloaded.  I'd suggest loading it in `onCreate()`, and reloading it in `onNewIntent()`.

Comment: Thanks CSmith for the answer. I am using onNewIntent method as:


    @Override
        protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
            super.onNewIntent(intent);
            if(intent.getStringExtra(STR_KEY) != null ) {
                webView.loadUrl(intent.getStringExtra(STR_KEY));
            }
            else
            {
                webView.loadUrl(uri);
            }
        }
Here, STR_KEY is the URL from FCM and uri is to handle whatsapp received links. Still not loading new URL, only resuming at xyz.com. Also,I have put mywebView.loadUrl() in onCreate()

Comment: Now that you have the code structure correct, add some Log.d statements to debug your code, ensure onNewIntent() is being received, that you're getting the URL's or StringExtra's you expect, etc

Comment: I added Log.d statements and observed that if `android:launchMode="singleTask"` and app is in background then onCreate() doesn't reload on clicking URL from Whatsapp, it is just bringing the app in foreground. But when I removed `android:launchMode="singleTask"` it is creating new instance and loading the URL successfully as wanted. I am stuck here.